# What is the difference between round() & trunc() function?

Tags: language-agnostic, math, background

I am very confused about these functions?

Comment: You can look from [Here](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/35094)

Answer (score 12):

In mathematics, [`rounding`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) means rounding to the nearest integer, so rounding 3.4 results in 3 and rounding 3.6 results in 4.

[`Truncating`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation), on the other hand, means removing the fractional part altogether, so either 3.4 or 3.6 results in 3.

Most programming languages and libraries follow this as well.

Answer (score 7):

`round( )` and `trunc( )`, in most programming languages, correspond to two of the four **basic rounding modes** specified by the IEEE-754 standard.

The four rounding modes, the corresponding rounding functions, and examples of how they behave on a variety of inputs, are:

```
rounding mode       function [1]     results of rounding:
                                     0.2    1.7   -2.6   -3.3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
round to nearest    round( ) [2]     0.0    2.0   -3.0   -3.0
round to zero       trunc( )         0.0    1.0   -2.0   -3.0
round to +infinity  ceil( )          1.0    2.0   -2.0   -3.0
round to -infinity  floor( )         0.0    1.0   -3.0   -4.0
```

[1] the IEEE-754 standard doesn't require these names, and not all languages use the same names.  These are merely the most common names in my experience.

[2] the `round( )` function in C and C-derived languages does not correspond exactly to the IEEE-754 round-to-nearest rounding mode.  Specifically, it differs in it's handling of exact halfway cases.  The C `round( )` function rounds "ties away from zero", which is probably what you learned in elementary school, but introduces bias into certain calculations.  The IEEE-754 round to nearest mode specifies that ties be rounded to the nearest even number, which is less likely to introduce bias while maintaining determinism.