# What is the reason to use trunc(date)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, truncate

What is the use of `trunc`? For example, I want to display the person age based on this 12-Mar-1996

```
select bo.journeystatus As "Journey Status",bo.bookingdate As "Booking Date",bo.fromdestination As "Location From",bo.todestination As "Desired Location", co.customerid As "Customer ID", co.customername As "Customer Name", co.customertel AS "Customer Phone No"
     , concat(TRUNC((SYSDATE - TO_DATE(co.customerdob, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))/ 365.25),' years old') as "Customer Age", co.customergender as "Gender"
from   booking bo, customer co
where  bo.journeystatus = 'Pending' and bo.bookingdate between to_date('01-'||in_month||'-'||in_year,'dd-mm-yyyy') AND to_date('30-'||in_month||'-'||in_year,'dd-mm-yyyy') and bo.customerid = co.customerid
group by bo.journeystatus, bo.fromdestination,bo.todestination, bo.bookingdate, co.customerid, co.customername, co.customertel, co.customerdob, co.customergender
order by bookingdate;
```

The above statement is correct, I just don't understand why it's needed? I went to read the those article online, but I still couldn't understand? Can anyone explain to me in a much simpler way?

Why is this `trunc(date)` needed?

```
concat(TRUNC((SYSDATE - TO_DATE(co.customerdob, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))/ 365.25),' years old')
```

Comment: In Oracle trunc(date) removes the time elment. Returns only the date (midnight). Datatype DATE always stores the date + time.

Comment: I see but, how do the value return (25) if sysdate - todate(), did i specify that only the year would be deducted?

Comment: "TRUNC removes the fractional part of the number. INT rounds numbers down to the nearest integer based on the value of the fractional part of the number." [Round vs. Trunc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2907258/10457877). Just delete your TRUNC() function, and you can see the difference :)

Comment: Note your example is not `trunc(date)` but `trunc(number)`, because `sysdate - someotherdate` gives the difference in days. Also, it seems odd that `co.customerdob` needs to be converted into a date. Normally you would store that as a date, and not need any conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets learn by example:

```
SELECT (SYSDATE - TO_DATE('30-03-1996', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) age
FROM DUAL;

-- Output - Total days (9281) and time (0.55410...) since 30-03-1996.
-- 
-- 9281.554108796296296296296296296296296296
--

SELECT (SYSDATE - TO_DATE('30-03-1996', 'DD-MM-YYYY')/ 365.25 age
FROM DUAL;

-- Output - Total years (25) and months/days/hours... (0.411519...) since 30-03-1996.
-- 
-- 25.41151953887494613025071615078459705428
--

-- Use trunc to cut off the decimal part
SELECT TRUNC((SYSDATE - TO_DATE('30-03-1996', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))/365.25) age
FROM DUAL;

-- Output - Total years (25) since 30-03-1996.
-- 
-- 25
--
```

Comment: OMGGG! Thank you so much for explaininggg! I really understand now!

Comment: In order to get the age of a person, I would rather use `months_between`

Comment: will bear that in mind, thanks for the advice! Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Gah!  What a hot mess of unformatted, run-on code.  I had to run it through an automated formatter just to be able to read it and make sense of it.  This doesn't answer your question, per se, but I couldn't let it pass without comment and the limitations of this platform would not allow an explanation in a 'comment'.

```
SELECT bo.journeystatus   AS "Journey Status",
       bo.bookingdate     AS "Booking Date",
       bo.fromdestination AS "Location From",
       bo.todestination   AS "Desired Location",
       co.customerid      AS "Customer ID",
       co.customername    AS "Customer Name",
       co.customertel     AS "Customer Phone No",
       Concat(Trunc(( SYSDATE - To_date(co.customerdob, 'DD-MON-YYYY') ) /
                    365.25),
       ' years old')      AS "Customer Age",
       co.customergender  AS "Gender"
FROM   booking bo,
       customer co
WHERE  bo.journeystatus = 'Pending'
       AND bo.bookingdate BETWEEN To_date('01-'
                                          ||in_month
                                          ||'-'
                                          ||in_year, 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND
                                      To_date('30-'
                                              ||in_month
                                              ||'-'
                                              ||in_year, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
       AND bo.customerid = co.customerid
GROUP  BY bo.journeystatus,
          bo.fromdestination,
          bo.todestination,
          bo.bookingdate,
          co.customerid,
          co.customername,
          co.customertel,
          co.customerdob,
          co.customergender
ORDER  BY bookingdate;
```

And this jumped out at me:

```
Concat(Trunc(( SYSDATE - To_date(co.customerdob, 'DD-MON-YYYY') ) /
```

The function TO_DATE takes a string as its input.  This means one of two conditions is true:

1. The column co.customerdob is, as to_date expects, a string data type (VARCHAR or VARCHAR2). If this is the case, you have a serious design flaw.  Dates/times should be in one of two possible date-time types - either DATE or TIMESTAMP.  Storing as DATE or TIMESTAMP enforces integrity and allows for simple date/time arithmetic.  Storing as VARCHAR allows neither.

OR

2. The column co.customerdob is, as it should be , a DATE.  And if this is the case, you have flawed code, because there will be an implicit TO_CHAR function in order to get co.customerdob into the string that TO_DATE is expeciting.  And this implicit to_char will depend on the default or session setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT, which may or may not be what you expect and depend on.

Comment: to solve the 2. statement, simply add this SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MON/YYYY';, then it would fix it